# Batch increment values

Tags: batch-file

I try to read a value from a file and increment it. But if I increment a value bigger than 8 it results to 1. Here's my code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (VERSION.txt) do set ver=%%i
set /a ver+=1
echo 0%ver%>>VERSION.txt
echo Build: %ver%
```

My file looks like:

```
06
07
08
01
02
03
```

Can somebody explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save you're value without the 0 :

test :

`set /a toto=08+1`

for the interpreter this is not a decimal,hexa or octal valid value.

You'll better do something like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (VERSION.txt) do set ver=%%i
set /a ver+=1
echo %ver%>VERSION.txt
echo Build: 0%ver%
```

**EDIT :**

You can make like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (VERSION.txt) do set "ver=%%i"
if  "%ver:~0,1%"=="0" set "ver=%ver:~1%"
set /a ver+=1
echo 0%ver%>>VERSION.txt
echo Build: 0%ver%
```

Comment: Without the trailing zero it doesn't work. What is the decimal number prefix?

Comment: There is not a decimal number prefix. You have to do a test on the first Char and if the value is zero remove it from the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with a leading zero are interpreted as octal numbers. `08` is not a valid octal number.

Answer (score 0):

As Joey already stated, any number with a leading zero is interpreted as octal.
But you can do the calculation by adding a one in front of it and strip it afterwards:

```
...
set /a ver=1%%i+1
echo %ver:~1%
...
```

run it with `echo on` to see, what happens.